# Gráficos SVG - HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

existe algún patrón específico para elaborar los gráficos svg? como atributos obligatorios o algo por el estilo... Explico el porque, pasa que yo mismo elabore un gráfico svg y cuando lo coloco junto a codigo HTML me funciona bien(o sea, con sus respectivas etiquetas ), pero si no quiero incluir el código del gráfico SVG directamente en el código HTML si no dejarlo en su archivo en formato .svg e incluirlo con una Tag `<img>` en mi código no me trae el grafico, y si intento hacerlo por CSS con el `background-image: url("data: image/svg+xml,utf8,<svg>...");` tampoco me muestra el gráfico svg, entonces de pronto estoy haciendo algo mal, aquí mi gráfico svg:
`<svg class="loading"><path d="M60 10 L10 30 L10 100 L60 120 L110 100 L110 30 Z" /><path d="M10 30 L60 50 M110 30 L60 50 M50 50 L160 120" /><path d="M10 100 L60 80 M110 100 L60 80 M60 120 L160 10"/></svg>`
Justo este código es el que guardo como .svg
No sé si pueda faltar algo a mi código, pero bueno gracias de antemano.
PD: Los fill y Strokes los tengo agregados con CSS, no directamente en codigo svg. Y aunque no creo que influya, tengo también unas animaciones simples con las propiedades `stroke-dasharray` y `stroke-dashoffset` en su respectivo `@keyframes`

Comment: SVG es un formato muy versátil, sin embargo sí que debes cumplir con ciertos requisitos para poder encapsularlo y que funcione correctamente desde un archivo separado de tu código HTML. Si vas a encapsularlo, debes migrar todo el código referente a los estilos dentro del archivo SVG. El mismo tiene la posibilidad de definir los estilos usando la etiqueta `<style></style>` y definiendo el nombre de las clases así: `.className{ prop: value }` donde `prop` es alguno de los atributos de clases de SVG como `stroke, fill, clip-path`, etc. Saludos

Comment: Primero que nada gracias por responder mauricio, segundo y creo que debí especificarlo arriba,  al momento de incluirlo como un <img> me retorna "error de lectura XML: contenido incorrecto tras un elemento XML del documento", seguido de su respectiva ubicación y el número de fila  y columna en codigo, indicando el inicio, ```<svg>``` y en cuanto a la ubicación no es alguna falla mía porque, tengo el archivo svg en el mismo directorio que mi código HTML y he intentado con rutas relativas o absolutas y nada...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analizando bien tu pregunta entiendo ahora mejor el problema que tienes. Por lo visto tienes el siguiente código dentro de tu archivo SVG:

```xml
<svg class="loading">
  <path d="M60 10 L10 30 L10 100 L60 120 L110 100 L110 30 Z" />
  <path d="M10 30 L60 50 M110 30 L60 50 M50 50 L160 120" />
  <path d="M10 100 L60 80 M110 100 L60 80 M60 120 L160 10"/>
</svg>
```

El cual funciona correctamente en un elemento tipo `<svg>` de HTML:

```html
<svg class="loading">
  <path d="M60 10 L10 30 L10 100 L60 120 L110 100 L110 30 Z" />
  <path d="M10 30 L60 50 M110 30 L60 50 M50 50 L160 120" />
  <path d="M10 100 L60 80 M110 100 L60 80 M60 120 L160 10"/>
</svg>
```

En el segundo caso, el SVG *funciona* porque todos sus elementos pertenecen al mismo espacio de nombre: *Namespace*, en este caso, su espacio de nombre es *HTML* y todos sus elementos forman parte del DOM.

(tomado de [*Acerca de SVG*](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#AboutSVG) traducción propia):

> Como un formato independiente o cuando es mezclado con otro documento XML, se usa la sintaxis XML [xml].El código SVG usado dentro de documentos HTML usa la sintaxis HTML [HTML].

Recordemos que SVG es un dialecto [*XML*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/XML), por lo tanto muchas de sus etiquetas pueden encontrarse en conflicto con las etiquetas de otro dialecto XML como *XHTML* (por ejemplo).

Para evitar estos conflictos cuando se enlaza una fuente *XML* dentro de un documento *HTML*, el motor de renderizado del navegador o del visor XML, verifica que cada fuente tenga su propio espacio de nombres.

Si la fuente a ser enlazada no tiene establecida apropiadamente su espacio de nombres, el visor ignora todo el código *XML* de la fuente enlazada.

Y eso es lo que ocurre cuando intentas enlazar tu archivo *SVG* actual mediante el atributo *src* de la etiqueta `<img>`, ya que no has establecido su espacio de nombres.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es declarar el espacio de nombre en tu etiqueta `<svg>` usando el atributo `xmlns` en tu archivo SVG. De la siguiente forma:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> ... </svg>
```

Además, en tu pregunta dices que todo el estilo del SVG lo has declarado en tu archivo de estilos CSS. Para que estos estilos funcionen en tu archivo SVG, debes declararlos en tu archivo SVG usando la etiqueta `<style>`.

Por ejemplo:

```html
<svg width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    .heart{fill: #F00}
  </style>
  <path class="heart" d="M 10,30
           A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
           A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
           Q 90,60 50,90
           Q 10,60 10,30 z"/>
</svg>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Excelente, aparte de aclararme ciertos puntos, resolví el problema.

Comment: ¿Cuál o cuáles eran? Primero, no había declarado el espacio de nombre en la etiqueta ```<svg>``` con el atributo xmlns, como tú lo has explicado y segundo, no definí los estilos dentro de la etiqueta ```<svg>``` sino antes de esta. Esa es la solución. Gracias mauricio!